OpenMaya (py/cpp) adding members to MFnContainerNode
I am attempting to recreate the following pymel functionality using python OpenMaya:
# Add mesh to container
# Assume we have created the container "cont" and mesh "pCube1"
pm.container("cont", e=1, f=1, includeShapes=True, includeTransform=True, addNode="pCube1")

Beyond fetching the MFnContainerNode, which has a handy getMembers() function, I would appreciate pointers to implementing something akin an addMember() function. I have gone down the MPlug rabbit hole and found the common hyperLayout MObject, but not entirely sure what to do with it, or if I am on the right track. Thanks in advance!
